# How to get the difference in years between two dates in sql - ORACLE?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to make a query in Oracle that shows all the records in which the employees are in the 'IT DEPARTMENT' and have been working between 3 and 8 years.

I have the table:

[image]

The **IT Department** has ID 60 in the table, how can I do the query with records from the table?
Please help! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from job_history
where end_date - start_date between  1095 and 2920
and department_id = 60;
```

1095 = 3*365

2920 = 8*365

Comment: Thanks, but the sentence does not include for the 'IT DEPARTMENT'

Comment: What?  You said IT dep is id 60.  There is no field in your example table that shows "IT Department"  Please clarify your question.